# Sort Array by data member in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So I've been trying to sort this array by price and haven't been able to get it right. Here's what I've got so far:

```
public abstract class Furniture implements Comparable<Furniture> {
    private String item;
    private double price;

    public Furniture(String item, double price) {
        this.item = item;
        this.price = price;
    }

     public double getPrice() {
            return price;
          }

     public String toString() {  
         return "Furniture Item: " + this.item + ", Price: $" + this.price;
     }

     public abstract String returnPurpose();

}
```

There's two data files that extend Furniture:

```
public class Seating extends Furniture {
    private int capacity;

    public Seating(String item, double price, int capacity) {
        super(item, price);
        this.capacity = capacity;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + ", Capacity: " + this.capacity;
    }


    @Override
    public double compareTo(Furniture o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.getPrice().compareTo(o.getPrice());
    }

    public String returnPurpose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}

public class Storage extends Furniture {
    private String used;
    private boolean isPowered;
    public Storage(String item, double price, boolean isPowered, String used) {
        super(item, price);
        this.used = used;
        this.isPowered = isPowered;
    }
    public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + ", Powered: " + this.isPowered + ", Used " + this.used;
    }
    @Override
    public double compareTo(Furniture o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.getPrice().compareTo(o.getPrice());
    }
    @Override
    public String returnPurpose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

This executable file is where most of the problems are. I try to sort the array but can't figure out how to express that I want it sorted by the price data member in Furniture.java:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestFurniture {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Storage storage1 = new Storage("Microwave",39.99,true,"for warming food");
        Seating seating1 = new Seating("Sofa",299.99,3);
        Storage storage2 = new Storage("Dresser",650,false,"to store clothing");
        Seating seating2 = new Seating("Love Seat",850,2);
        Storage storage3 = new Storage("Refrigerator",1400,true,"to store food");
        Seating seating3 = new Seating("Stool",140,1);
        Furniture[] furnarray = {storage1,seating1,storage2,seating2,storage3,seating3};
        System.out.println("Before ordering by price");
        for (int i = 0; i < furnarray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(furnarray[i]);
        Arrays.sort(furnarray);
        System.out.println("After ordering by price");
        for (int j = 0; j < furnarray.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(furnarray[j]);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `compareTo` method defines the class' natural ordering, which you implemented as ordering by price. Could you elaborate on what exactly the is the problem? Are you getting the wrong results?

Comment: Shouldn't `compareTo` return an `int`?

Comment: I'm getting an error with "return this.getPrice().compareTo(o.getPrice());"

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(furnarray))
```

Sorry you are already using Arrays.sort I was actually not aware of that method exists. when you call it it calls your

```
    public double compareTo(Furniture o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.getPrice().compareTo(o.getPrice());
}
```

methods.

Comment: But how does that sort with price?

Answer (score 0):

The result of [`Comparable<T>.compareTo(T)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) is an `int`. Change your method signature. Something like,

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Furniture o) {
    return this.getPrice().compareTo(o.getPrice());
}
```